# Better Code for Authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, code-reuse

I am really new to PHP and Laravel and i am a little embarrassed for asking this Questions but none of the things i am trying to reuse code in my Controllers work.

I have this function in my PagesController for setting up the welcome-view of my Laravel Web Application:

```
public function welcome(Request $request)
{
    $cities = City::all();

    $user_id = $request->session()->pull('user_id');
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    if($user !== null )$request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);

    return view('welcome',[
        'cities' => $cities,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

the important stuff are the three lines which gets the user_id and finds the fitting User from the Database.

I'd like to define a function in my BaseController and use it in every other Controller as well.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: shouldn't this be inside middleware instead?

Comment: Whats wrong with `Auth::user()`?

Comment: I don't really get the middleware stuff. I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/rootinc/laravel-azure-middleware

But i need some explenation how i use this now

Comment: You can use the `Auth` facade. You can get the logged in user_id by `Auth::user()->id`. I don't see the necessity of doing all these manually via sessions.

Comment: When i try ```Auth::user()->id``` There comes an error message "trying to get property of non-object"
I did the extended installation of this tutorial https://github.com/rootinc/laravel-azure-middleware#extended-installation and i have no clue how to proceed next!!

Comment: I just need anything that helps me understanding what i am doing or how this middleware and azure AD and laravel stuff works together

Comment: try `auth()->check()` to see if the user is logged in and then you could try `auth()->user()->id` to get the id of the user logged in

Comment: Curious... you load the user using a session variable and then write that same value back to the session?

Comment: @Yoshi did u see the extended installation here? https://github.com/rootinc/laravel-azure-middleware#extended-installation

Comment: auth()->check() isn't true and i don't know why. Did anyone of you look at the link i sent you a few times to tell me what this is?

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys.. I just can't figure out what i am doing and i think nobody can help me right now.. I will do this with seesion variables because i have to finish this work soon and after this deadline i will try to improve my System with better authentication.. Thanks to all of you for trying to help me